# Como executar scripts no startup do CentoS?

Tags: linux, centos, shell-script

Boa tarde, como faço para executar um script no CentOs 6.5?

Estou executando em

```
 /etc/rc.local 

 /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

e não está carregando os comandos:

```
sh /etc/init.d/script
```

o comando funciona fora do script.

Comment: Seria no startup do sistema!

Comment: André, esse comment foi uma resposta? Nesse caso seria interessante colocares no campo das respostas e partilhares com outros.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você esta com os comandos setados no arquivo "script"

se for isso tente da permissão total ao arquivo e transformar o mesmo em executável.

> chmod +777 /etc/init.d/script
>
> chmod +x /etc/init.d/script

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/rc.local` ou `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` não são mais executados devido a mudanças no CentOS.

Pra continuar usando eles, você precisa manter `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` como executável:

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

**Debug**

Para debugar o problema, seria uma boa idéia redirecionar a saída do script (`/etc/init.d/script > /var/log/seu_log`) para ter certeza se o script está sendo executado ou não.

**Exemplo:**

```
# touch > /root/meu_script.sh
# touch > /var/log/meu_log && chmod 777 /var/log/meu_log
```

Salve o conteúdo:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Nossa! Estou vivo!'
```

Dê permissão:

```
chmod +x /root/meu_script.sh
```

E agende sua execução no boot para:

```
/etc/init.d/script > /var/log/meu_log
```

Após o boot, veja se o arquivo `/var/log/meu_log` está vazio ou escrito. Se estiver vazio, obviamente o script não rodou no boot.